# Selecting a default value in a <select> statement in a XSL file

Tags: html, xslt, html-select

I have a list of  items like how its listed below, and I'm trying to get that option selected by default which has a certain tag within the "listing" tag.

```
<select>
<xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/>_type</xsl:attribute>
<option><xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:if test="listing/Chat"><xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>Chat</xsl:attribute>Chat</option>
...
```

Am I placing the xsl:if incorrectly?

Comment: This is pretty hard to make out. Can you post what result you're looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code isn't valid because you've nested one `<xsl:attribute>` tag inside another. I believe you want something like one of the following:

```
<select name="{@id}_type">
    <option value="Chat">
        <xsl:if test="listing/Chat">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:text>Chat</xsl:text>
    </option>
</select>
```

or

```
<select name="{@id}_type">
    <xsl:if test="listing/Chat">
        <option value="Chat" selected="selected">Chat</option>
    </xsl:if>
</select>
```

The former always displays the "Chat" option, but only selects it if the condition is met. The latter doesn't display "Chat" at all unless the condition is met.

Comment: Thanks guys! I based it off Ben's code to get it to work. Apologies for not posting it clearly above.


Final code looks like this:

<select name="{@id}_type">

<option value="Chat"><xsl:if test="listing/Chat"><xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if><xsl:text>Chat</xsl:text></option>

...
...

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from the code you've provided, but I'm guessing you want results that look like this:

```
<select name="000_type">
<option value="chat" selected="selected"/>
<option value="chat"/>
</select>
```

In which case you want XSL that looks like this:

```
<xsl:element name="select">
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="concat(@id,'_type'))"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="option">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
       <xsl:value-of select="chat"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:if test="listing/Chat">
       <xsl:attribute name="selected">
          <xsl:text>selected</xsl:text>
       </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
```